# playwright get all options value in a multiple select

Tags: c#, playwright

I have this Select:

```html
<select size="4" name="Select1" multiple="multiple" id="Select1">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
    <option value="6">F</option>
 </select>
```

how can I get all the options value using playwright  hopefully an example using C#

Answer (score 3):

In node.js to get all the select options you can use:

```
const options = await page.$$eval('#Select1 > option', (els) => {
  return els.map(option => option.textContent)
})
console.log(options);
```

The equivalent for **page.$$eval** in .Net is **Page.QuerySelectorAllAsync(selector)**.

You can check the documentation here:

https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-query-selector-all

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
string[] values = (await Page.QuerySelectorAllAsync("#Select1 > option"))
    .Select(async option => await option.GetAttributeAsync("value"))
    .ToArray();
```